# Tensorflow raised error: ImportError: cannot import name 'export_saved_model'

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

seems like "import tensorflow as tf" directly raise this error

Colab link:https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Jr0j_I_npKQxcQ1ggJQFHTqoJHmt9Bqk

Answer (score 15, accepted):

sorry, the problem is that installing tensorflow-gpu does not uninstall tensorflow and tensorflow 2.2.0 has introduced some changes that are incompatible with tensorflow 1.14.0.

if you do

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
!pip uninstall -y tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
```

it will work

Comment: Just want to add that you make sure you remove tensorflow in conda and pip.