# Downgrading tensorflow version on colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Im having problems installing an older version of tensorflow on colab. I tried the solution suggested on [this page here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60879608/tensorflow-raised-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-export-saved-model/60880012#60880012?newreg=5824dde3e7e64721b123d4e7066eadf8), without any success. Any suggestions?

Link to colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1F7jJ-sJXX78ldAt-ri2VEgto7pZOctI6?usp=sharing

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for TF1

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
```

You can check the version

```
print(tf.__version__)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install specific version of Tensorflow by running this cell:

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.__version__ != "2.9.0":
  !pip install -U -q tensorflow==2.9.0
print(tf.__version__)
```

This is not the last step yet, for this to completely take effect, click on

> runtime > restart runtime

Then re-run the above cell, it will apply the new version of tensorflow