# Colab ImportError: cannot import name 'squeeze_or_expand_dimensions'

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

following [Transfer Learning with TensorFlow Hub for TFLite](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_lite/tflite_c02_transfer_learning.ipynb) tutorial,fisrt step is

```
!pip install -q -U "tensorflow-gpu=2.0.0b1"
```

setup:

```
import os

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

print("Version: ", tf.__version__)
print("Eager mode: ", tf.executing_eagerly())
print("Hub version: ", hub.__version__)
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else "NOT AVAILABLE")
```

an error raised:**ImportError: cannot import name 'export_saved_model'**
after i tried

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
!pip uninstall -y tensorflow
!pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
```

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60879608/tensorflow-raised-error-importerror-cannot-import-name-export-saved-model), another error raised:
**ImportError: cannot import name 'squeeze_or_expand_dimensions'**

also,i tried `!pip install --upgrade tensorflow`,and another error raised...**ImportError: cannot import name 'collections_abc'**
i'm stuck here...

Comment: @Jeff Snyder my reputation can't afford to comment your answer, could you help me here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run `!pip install -q -U "tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0b1"`.

Under "Runtime" menu "Change runtime type" to "GPU" and "Factory reset runtime".

```py
import os

import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

print("Version: ", tf.__version__)
print("Eager mode: ", tf.executing_eagerly())
print("Hub version: ", hub.__version__)
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else "NOT AVAILABLE")
```

Output:

```
Version:  2.2.0
Eager mode:  True
Hub version:  0.8.0
GPU is available
```

Comment: Worked! ! thx a lot just don't know why the tutorial(from udacity) run that

Comment: I'm glad I could help.